# How can we get the last accessed pipeline from SFCC (demandware.)

Tags: demandware

I need to get the last rendered pipeline name. Is there any method to get the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use ClickStream class, which has a property named "last", the last.getPipelineName() will return the last rendered pipeline name.

Comment: Please note that this may not always be 100% accurate, but should suffice for most needs. (Particularly for sites with AJAX or customers using multiple tabs)